# What data structure would I need to use to construct a minimum spanning tree in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a class `Node` similar to Java's class `Point` with `x` and `y` coordinates, which I paint onto a `JPanel`. I'm trying to create a minimum spanning tree for a set of such nodes on a Euclidean graph, which I would then paint onto the panel as well. But I can't really figure out the data structure I'd need to do create the tree efficiently in the first place.

I've tried using `LinkedLists` and `ArrayLists` to implement Prim's algorithm, but they seem to make things overly complicated. What data structure should I be looking into for this instead?

Comment: use a [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)?

Comment: What's with the [tag:traveling-salesman] tag? MST != TSP route (an MST doesn't even produce a path at all). Have you looked for an open-source Java MST implementation?

Comment: Okay, I just put that in there because i'm using a MST to create a complete hamiltonian cycle (it would be have at most 2 times the optimal cost). I'll remove the tag though. I've seen a couple Java implementations, but they're very confusing to me, so I'm just trying to create one from scratch to try to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph can be represented by adjacency list. I generally use `Vector` to create adjacency lists. They are very convenient to handle. Also use `PriorityQueue` to get minimum path cost.

Comment: What would be the difference between using a Vector or ArrayList; I was under the impression that the former was simply a synchronized version of the latter. I already tried using an `ArrayList` (since I thought using either wouldn't matter), but failed to do so... it doesn't seem like i'm implementing it as I should be.

Comment: I have always use Vector only. ArrayList would also serve the same I suppose.

Comment: @Trust http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated

Comment: I understand the differences; I simply meant that in this case, they are essentially the same (I think).